# iPhone App Crash

Tags: iphone

App is crashing when app opened without any action in iPhone, iPhone goes to lock mode, When i  unlock iPhone and touch the app. It is  Crashing.

```
Log file:


Incident Identifier: 5E7FCE6E-7D86-4C0D-8FDA-B3D3437B4914
CrashReporter Key:   de15cdf13c604c89257f5156f3d3e0daea905d29
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         Charles Town [3788]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B9D9FCB0-9105-4D02-A817-79F6C3DE9FC8/Charles Town.app/Charles Town
Identifier:      Charles Town
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-01-24 16:23:55.834 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148a)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6365786d
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3199f464 0x3199c000 + 13412
1   Charles Town                    0x00028990 0x1000 + 162192
2   Charles Town                    0x00029506 0x1000 + 165126
3   Charles Town                    0x00029798 0x1000 + 165784
4   Charles Town                    0x0003180a 0x1000 + 198666
5   Charles Town                    0x00014d60 0x1000 + 81248
6   CoreFoundation                  0x31477fe6 0x31430000 + 294886
7   Charles Town                    0x00005bce 0x1000 + 19406
8   Foundation                      0x31cf6806 0x31cc4000 + 206854
9   Foundation                      0x31cf6788 0x31cc4000 + 206728
10  CFNetwork                       0x3465047e 0x34641000 + 62590
11  CFNetwork                       0x346451f2 0x34641000 + 16882
12  CFNetwork                       0x346450e4 0x34641000 + 16612
13  CFNetwork                       0x34645096 0x34641000 + 16534
14  CFNetwork                       0x34645014 0x34641000 + 16404
15  CFNetwork                       0x34644f92 0x34641000 + 16274
16  CoreFoundation                  0x314867d6 0x31430000 + 354262
17  CoreFoundation                  0x314585b0 0x31430000 + 165296
18  CoreFoundation                  0x31457e54 0x31430000 + 163412
19  CoreFoundation                  0x31457c80 0x31430000 + 162944
20  CoreFoundation                  0x31457b88 0x31430000 + 162696
21  GraphicsServices                0x35d664a4 0x35d62000 + 17572
22  GraphicsServices                0x35d66550 0x35d62000 + 17744
23  UIKit                           0x338d5322 0x3389e000 + 226082
24  UIKit                           0x338d2e8c 0x3389e000 + 216716
25  Charles Town                    0x00002f40 0x1000 + 8000
26  Charles Town                    0x00002ef4 0x1000 + 7924

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31192974 0x31165000 + 186740
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3123c704 0x31165000 + 882436
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3123c174 0x31165000 + 881012
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3123bb98 0x31165000 + 879512
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311e024a 0x31165000 + 504394
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311d8970 0x31165000 + 473456

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311e09e0 0x31165000 + 506336
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311e0364 0x31165000 + 504676
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311d8970 0x31165000 + 473456

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31166268 0x31165000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31168354 0x31165000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31458648 0x31430000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31457ed2 0x31430000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31457c80 0x31430000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31457b88 0x31430000 + 162696
6   WebCore                         0x33d9f124 0x33ce8000 + 749860
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311df886 0x31165000 + 501894
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311d4a88 0x31165000 + 457352

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311e09e0 0x31165000 + 506336
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311e0364 0x31165000 + 504676
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311d8970 0x31165000 + 473456

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31166268 0x31165000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31168354 0x31165000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31458648 0x31430000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31457ed2 0x31430000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31457c80 0x31430000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31457b88 0x31430000 + 162696
6   Foundation                      0x31cf15f6 0x31cc4000 + 185846
7   Foundation                      0x31ccf192 0x31cc4000 + 45458
8   Foundation                      0x31cc8242 0x31cc4000 + 16962
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311df886 0x31165000 + 501894
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x311d4a88 0x31165000 + 457352

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3118a68c 0x31165000 + 153228
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3148f662 0x31430000 + 390754
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311df886 0x31165000 + 501894
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x311d4a88 0x31165000 + 457352

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00038737    r1: 0x33bafb50      r2: 0x3e216100      r3: 0x3e216100
    r4: 0x63657865    r5: 0x33bafb50      r6: 0x0017b8b0      r7: 0x2fdfe8b4
    r8: 0x0017b820    r9: 0x03802128     r10: 0x0017df90     r11: 0x0099ba00
    ip: 0x3145332d    sp: 0x2fdfe888      lr: 0x00028997      pc: 0x3199f464
  cpsr: 0x200f0030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x3dfff +Charles Town armv7  <96455969ff682f6b014f2536a9227ca3> /var/mobile/Applications/B9D9FCB0-9105-4D02-A817-79F6C3DE9FC8/Charles Town.app/Charles Town
   0xf4000 -    0xf5fff  dns.so armv7  <fcefecb2d5e095ba88127eec3af57ec0> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7  <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30122000 - 0x30177fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3019a000 - 0x301e4fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3024e000 - 0x302fdfff  WebKit armv7  <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x30319000 - 0x30320fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3033c000 - 0x30429fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <c72b45f471df092dbd849081f7a3ef53> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x30569000 - 0x3056afff  CoreSurface armv7  <f7caaf43609cfe0e475dfe83790edb4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x30666000 - 0x306e2fff  AVFoundation armv7  <4c7356c795e01bd5c21b00a409a07476> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x30746000 - 0x3074ffff  CoreVideo armv7  <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30750000 - 0x3075bfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <fabaddbcbc8c02bab0261df9d78e0e25> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3075f000 - 0x30761fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x30792000 - 0x3079cfff  AccountSettings armv7  <19c79f81d5d55fe2e6b618fcdc28258e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3079d000 - 0x307a3fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30853000 - 0x30854fff  DataMigration armv7  <babbc72d4d48325de147d5103d7bc00d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x309e4000 - 0x30a16fff  AppSupport armv7  <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30a1d000 - 0x30a54fff  Security armv7  <cd28e102950634ae7167ddee9c686d36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30a5d000 - 0x30b0bfff  QuartzCore armv7  <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30c3d000 - 0x30c5afff  AppleAccount armv7  <e3833276f8877499c8dd76b3b3d88501> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x30c7e000 - 0x30caafff  DataAccess armv7  <6b9b5235b449335ce5c66d53f32004cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x30d3c000 - 0x30d3ffff  ActorKit armv7  <f5d038591e564646e9237a59c6c14293> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x30d54000 - 0x30d61fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x30e17000 - 0x30e4dfff  CoreLocation armv7  <e19b7aa132318fc90618a663bd576461> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x30e71000 - 0x30faefff  MediaToolbox armv7  <a18bbcc41a38917fe0ae5e183d3f6b07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x30faf000 - 0x30feefff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <a7c117c92607a512823d307b8fdd0151> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3101d000 - 0x3101ffff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <30a5f1edcdb9ffe868a620199a4cbe12> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x31020000 - 0x3102cfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31077000 - 0x3115ffff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x31160000 - 0x31163fff  IOSurface armv7  <deff02882166bf16d0765d68f0542cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x31165000 - 0x31276fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31324000 - 0x31336fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <cd2a699aa5036bdad0517603ba4db839> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x31337000 - 0x31371fff  IOKit armv7  <eb932cc42d60e55d9a4d0691bcc3d9ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x313fa000 - 0x3140dfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <855aefc263c6c20e6cf8723ea36125a2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x31425000 - 0x31429fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e861a330d14702f148ca5133dcbe954c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x31430000 - 0x31516fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x31517000 - 0x31519fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3151b000 - 0x3151efff  CertUI armv7  <5f37446c6b65a8c38ab6233c2e33da66> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x3153d000 - 0x31546fff  ITSync armv7  <87d409553f90e41a01afce047dc2e8fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x31549000 - 0x3154cfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a2af7147f5538d7669b14fa7b19b5a7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3155c000 - 0x3167cfff  CoreGraphics armv7  <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3167d000 - 0x3168dfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6767a1e2afbc86a1ec63dd784f5d3677> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x31697000 - 0x316c8fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <bb7ff9014b1dabec2acce95d41f05b59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x316cf000 - 0x31702fff  iCalendar armv7  <6eb50e720d642f5ac510a36989b276b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x31703000 - 0x31705fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <e66758bcda6da5d7f9b54fa5c4de6da2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x317f9000 - 0x3183cfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <27ac7f05482a8aa9977150f34f9be6eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3186b000 - 0x3187afff  Notes armv7  <7d7a3d10a349471cd2757a479d131b31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x3187b000 - 0x31991fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <e7fbb2ac586567e574dc33d7bb5c4dc9> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x31992000 - 0x3199bfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <9f1760206eaef20c605c5d98e45c823e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x3199c000 - 0x31a5dfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <aaf5671a35f9ac20d5846703dafaf4c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x31a5e000 - 0x31a66fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <6d6c62f52219d27be50f1d7c39a68dc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x31a7d000 - 0x31a8afff  OpenGLES armv7  <a12565ffb5bb42e3019f1957cd4951d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31a9a000 - 0x31ad7fff  CoreMedia armv7  <4ea4d349e886206d1ecf5bae870f3f04> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31ae0000 - 0x31ae3fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x31b29000 - 0x31b52fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31b58000 - 0x31b5ffff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31bcc000 - 0x31be1fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <ea156820997ae9a2baf664d0f79f18d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x31cc4000 - 0x31de3fff  Foundation armv7  <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31de4000 - 0x31e17fff  QuickLook armv7  <8c54395accc7ffc84766ff3e9b24beb1> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x31e18000 - 0x31e63fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33856000 - 0x33884fff  MIME armv7  <1989502ce4da514314647c6a0098d8e7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x33886000 - 0x3389cfff  EAP8021X armv7  <36659ec2b9def7b5798a05327e369247> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3389e000 - 0x33c1ffff  UIKit armv7  <de1cbd3219a74e4d41b30428f428e223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33c5e000 - 0x33ce7fff  Message armv7  <69cb7cb1d1d7865fc04dc341544174b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x33ce8000 - 0x342d0fff  WebCore armv7  <d6bd9cf88ee82ab6b0e33e0ae1190772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x34342000 - 0x3436bfff  ContentIndex armv7  <247576cb4f1ff8e92650ae3cb4973760> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3438c000 - 0x343e5fff  EventKit armv7  <037c4bb5e2529e6004d0e1f3d95a84cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x343e6000 - 0x34405fff  Bom armv7  <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x344ea000 - 0x34623fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x34628000 - 0x34628fff  Accelerate armv7  <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x34641000 - 0x34700fff  CFNetwork armv7  <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3471b000 - 0x3473cfff  MobileSync armv7  <cff20dfe818febca9f3232426d59a42d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x34941000 - 0x34944fff  ApplePushService armv7  <9d1eb7b11f0f146c941efbab2c055606> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x34952000 - 0x3495afff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b29d4c5e300ef81060e38f72bb583c02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3495b000 - 0x34bf5fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34bf6000 - 0x34c36fff  CoreAudio armv7  <f32e03ee4c68f0db23f05afc9a3cc94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34c4e000 - 0x34c86fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <374bd566263e8929c10d50d6a6a48a46> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35227000 - 0x3532efff  CoreData armv7  <29b1ab7d339e42a6ff6923e54cf43e7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x35336000 - 0x353dffff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <b3d82f80a777cb1434052ea2d232e3df> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x353e1000 - 0x3548efff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x354b4000 - 0x354bcfff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x354d9000 - 0x354f9fff  PrintKit armv7  <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x354fa000 - 0x3553cfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3553d000 - 0x3558afff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3567c000 - 0x356ccfff  GMM armv7  <2b63c1e1ce647e031a8a491e156f04d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x35a37000 - 0x35a3cfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <cec3f3271fc267c32c169ed03e312d63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x35a95000 - 0x35a95fff  vecLib armv7  <e53d234e808c77d286161095f92c58cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x35b9f000 - 0x35ba5fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <7e279d3b6d1e1fd7dc8c8a883255fa17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x35bcc000 - 0x35bfbfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x35bff000 - 0x35ca0fff  Celestial armv7  <b411f4662383ec24dbfbcde8f4c23d67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x35ca1000 - 0x35d10fff  ProofReader armv7  <d2e62a8ab7e1460c7f6de8913c703e6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35d1a000 - 0x35d61fff  MessageUI armv7  <bb7d161bb6c699afb2e1744ece115ae8> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x35d62000 - 0x35d6efff  GraphicsServices armv7  <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x35db1000 - 0x35e44fff  ImageIO armv7  <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x35e52000 - 0x35e85fff  AddressBook armv7  <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x35ea2000 - 0x35f38fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <45665471fd70b0733b206d8166df74ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35f4a000 - 0x35f4ffff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <5f73c7138ee1cb7103a98aec99f9ed88> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x35f86000 - 0x35fbcfff  CoreText armv7  <b9b5c21b2d2a28abc47842c78c026ddf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x35fbd000 - 0x35fbffff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35ffc000 - 0x36015fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ee16b5cee12a8947c8e511ed51ae7fef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3607f000 - 0x3608efff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <8f2fc7e811bc57f7a09d7df81c329e1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
```

Thanks

Vadivelu

Comment: Please do not post a crash log like this unless it is symbolicated, also you need to include the actual code so that the line that caused the crash can be seen. Posting just the raw crash log is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if what is happening is that when the screen is locked, critical assets to your application are released; and they are not re-aquired when the application comes back from lock.

Without codez it is difficult to ascertain exactly *what* resources; but it is, at the very least, a starting point for your own investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your codes instead? I can only understand its a bad access issue from the log. Means the app is trying to access something in the memory that is not there.

Comment: One more Crash: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Answer (score 0):

Is your app trying to access some of the features of iphone that is restricted to only apple apps (reinstalled apps in your iphone). if that is the case than the app will not run unless you jailbreak your iphone(which i dont recommend). so check whats the private API your app is using and try to find a work around for that API.

If that is not the case than every time the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` comes remember that you are trying to access something that is already released. so try to give this out before my first suggestion.

Comment: This is not happing every time and not using any private API

Comment: hey are you trying to run app for iPhone OS 4.2.1 on iphone 2

Comment: Yes, I am using OS 4.2.1 on iPhone2.